# How to create a recursive relationship in OpenERP

Tags: python, recursion, odoo

I have the below model:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from openerp.osv import osv, fields


class provincias(osv.osv):
    _name = 'co.provincias'
    _descripcion = 'Registro de Provincias'
    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Nombre de la Provincia'),
        'parent_id': fields.many2one('co.provincias', 'Provincia Padre'),
         'child_ids': fields.one2many(
            'co.provincias',
            'parent_id',
            'Sub-provincias'),
        }
provincias()
```

For some unknown reason I do not believe the table in the database, but leave the model without recursion if I work, it is like this:

```
        # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from openerp.osv import osv, fields


class provincias(osv.osv):
    _name = 'co.provincias'
    _descripcion = 'Registro de Provincias'
    _columns = {
        'name': fields.char('Nombre de la Provincia'),
        }
provincias()
```

Do you have any suggestions? regards

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but maybe you'll have to use a many2many relationship:

```
child_ids= fields.many2many('co.provincias',
                        'co_provincias_rel',
                        'parent_id',
                        'child_id')
```